# Fill a 3D object plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, tikz-3dplot

I want to draw an object in 3D an fill it entirely. The object is defined in [0,1]^3, and I know the upper limit function, and lower limit function.
The problem is I know how to draw the upper and lower bound, but I don't know how to fill in between (and fill in between does not work... or at least I don't achieve to make it work!). Here is my current code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
    pbar(\x, \y)=min(0.5+0.4*\y, 0.5+0.4-0.4*\x); 
    plow(\x, \y)=max(0.5-0.25+(0.4-0.15)*\y, 0.5-0.25*\x); 
}]
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
\begin{axis}[
zmax=1.00, zmin=0, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmax=1, xmin=0,
view/h=55,
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(blue), color=(red)},
xlabel = $X$,
ylabel = $Y$,
zlabel = {$F$},
]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{pre main}
\addplot3[name path=pmax,  
    surf,
    faceted color=gray, 
    samples=15, opacity=0.3, 
    domain=0:1,y domain=0:1
] {pbar(x,y)};

\addplot3[name path=pmin, 
    surf,
    faceted color=gray,  
    samples=15, opacity=0.3, 
    domain=0:1,y domain=0:1
] {plow(x,y)};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result I obtain looks like this: [image]
I'd like to have it as a complete "closed shape", such that it's a filled polygon. (may also change the view such that it's more visible but that's for later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 3D in PGFPlots or TikZ. A 3D fill would also not make much sense in a graph.
Everything is 2D and drawn in the order as in the code, so you need to plot the upper surface after the lower surface. If you want the back and front surface filled with a color, you can do it like below. If you want a mesh, you can either `\clip` a `mesh`(`surf`) plot for a square mesh or you can use a `patch` plot that would have a triangular mesh.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
pbar(\x,\y)=min(0.5+0.4*\y, 0.5+0.4-0.4*\x); 
plow(\x,\y)=max(0.5-0.25+(0.4-0.15)*\y, 0.5-0.25*\x); 
}]
\begin{axis}[
view/h=55,
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(blue), color=(red)},
xlabel = $X$, ylabel = $Y$, zlabel = {$F$},
]
\fill[teal, opacity=0.1]
  (0,0,{plow(0,0)}) -- (0,1,{plow(0,1)}) -- (1,1,{plow(1,1)}) -- 
  (1,1,{pbar(1,1)}) -- (0,1,{pbar(0,1)}) -- (0,0,{pbar(0,0)}) -- cycle;
\addplot3[ 
surf,
faceted color=gray,  
samples=15, opacity=0.5, 
domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,
] {plow(x,y)};
\addplot3[  
surf,
faceted color=gray, 
samples=15, opacity=0.6, 
domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,
] {pbar(x,y)};
\fill[red, opacity=0.5]
  (0,0,{plow(0,0)}) -- (1,0,{plow(1,0)}) -- (1,1,{plow(1,1)}) -- 
  (1,1,{pbar(1,1)}) -- (1,0,{pbar(1,0)}) -- (0,0,{pbar(0,0)}) -- cycle;
\draw[gray] (1,0,{plow(1,0)}) -- (1,0,{pbar(1,0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Colored shape in 3D graph]

*Edit:* Surfaces covered with `patch` plots:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
pbar(\x,\y)=min(0.5+0.4*\y, 0.5+0.4-0.4*\x); 
plow(\x,\y)=max(0.5-0.25+(0.4-0.15)*\y, 0.5-0.25*\x); 
}]
\begin{axis}[
view/h=55,
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(blue), color=(red)},
xlabel = $X$, ylabel = $Y$, zlabel = {$F$},
]
\addplot3[
patch, patch type=triangle, patch refines=6, 
faceted color=gray, opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (0,0,{plow(0,0)}) (0,1,{plow(0,1)}) (0,1,{pbar(0,1)}) 
  (1,1,{plow(1,1)}) (0,1,{plow(0,1)}) (0,1,{pbar(0,1)})};
\addplot3[ 
surf,
faceted color=gray,  
samples=15, opacity=0.6, 
domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,
] {plow(x,y)};
\addplot3[  
surf,
faceted color=gray, 
samples=15, opacity=0.6, 
domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,
] {pbar(x,y)};
\addplot3[
patch, patch type=triangle, patch refines=6, 
faceted color=gray, opacity=0.6] coordinates {
  (0,0,{plow(0,0)}) (1,0,{plow(1,0)}) (1,0,{pbar(1,0)}) 
  (1,1,{plow(1,1)}) (1,0,{plow(1,0)}) (1,0,{pbar(1,0)})};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Colored 3D shape with a mesh in a graph]

Comment: Thanks that should do it! (if I change the angle of the view because we do not see much with this one unfortunately)